# use .replace to replace only first instance of character

Tags: javascript, replace

struggling with this code as part of a course - it should only erase the first instance of each character, but my loop erases all instances.
Thinking of deleting the instance from toerase once tested then rebuilding after run but seems overly convoluted. How do I use inbuilt replace function to solve this?

```
disappearString = (myString, toErase) => {
    // Place your code here
    
    //let to earase an array of string to disappear
    var toErase = stringToDisappear.split('');

    //toErase = toErase.join(||');//join array with ||(or) didn't work - binned this idea

    //console.log (toErase); //checking its come as an array

        let result = ""; //define result as empty
    //loop to erase each instance - but for f**s sake I don't want to do that, just remove the first instance"!
      for (let i = 0; i < myString.length; i++) {
        let letter = myString[i]; //declare letter
        if (!toErase.includes(letter) ) { //check if letter is the same as any of toerase
          result += myString[i]; //if letter is not in toerase print it.
      
        }
      };
      return result;
    };




// DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
let testStrings = [
    "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog",
    "hello world",
    "software engineering is fun",
    "i like javascript",
    "clown case",
    "rhythms"
]

let stringToDisappear = "aeiou"

let correctStrings = [
    "th qck brwn fox jumps over the lzy dog",
    "hll world",
    "sftwr engneering is fn",
    " lik jvascript",
    "clwn cs",
    "rhythms"
]

for (let strIdx = 0; strIdx < testStrings.length; strIdx++) {
    let test = testStrings[strIdx];
    let correct = correctStrings[strIdx];

    let got = disappearString(test, stringToDisappear);

    if (got == correct) {
        console.log(`${strIdx + 1}: Testing ${test}: Correct!`);
    } else {
        console.log(`${strIdx + 1}: Testing ${test}: Wrong, got ${got}, expected ${correct}`);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)? Replacing the first character is what `replace` does by default.

Comment: yeah but don't understand how to put it into a function...

Comment: The issue in your solution is that you aren't removing the character from the list in `toErase` after you've done the replacement. Using the first test string, after `e` is replaced the first time, you should then remove `e` from the `toErase` array. Then when you encounter `e` again, it will not be replaced.

Comment: yeah I understand that - how do I go about doing that? Think its going to get clunky no?

Comment: It's pretty straightforward actually. One way would be to use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):
`toErase = toErase.filter(entry => entry != letter);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to fully understand. You have an array of strings 'testStrings', you have a string 'stringToDisappear' with some letters in. You want to delete each letter from 'stringToDisappear' from each string of the array of string 'testStrings', once. And using replace.

If I'm right in the understanding of the question:

```js
let testStrings = [
  "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog",
  "hello world",
  "software engineering is fun",
  "i like javascript",
  "clown case",
  "rhythms"
];

const stringToDisappear = "aeiou";
const strAr = stringToDisappear.split('');

for (let i = 0; i < strAr.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < testStrings.length; j++) {
    testStrings[j] = testStrings[j].replace(strAr[i], '');
  }
}
console.log(testStrings);
```

Comment: no not quite - it needs to work in the format specified and I can't get your solution to work like that